# Finding derivative of $|x|^p$ by the definition

Tags: limits, derivatives, factoring

How do I find the the derivative of $|x|^p$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $p\in [1,\infty)$ via the definition of the derivative? I know the derivative is equal to $px|x|^{p-2}$. If I use the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/finding-the-derivative-of-x-using-the-limit-definition) question, I don't get to anywhere useful:

$$f(x)'=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{|x+h|^p-|x|^p}{h}=\frac{(|x+h|^p-|x|^p)(|x+h|^p+|x|^p)}{h(|x+h|^p+|x|^p)}=\frac{|x+h|^{2p}-|x|^{2p}}{h(|x+h|^p+|x|^p)}$$

So I don't think myself that adopting the method from the question is correct. But then I can't think of any other way to get to the desired answer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that if $x>0$, $|x|=x$, and if $x<0$, $|x|=-x$...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Do you mean I should calculcate $\frac{|x+h|^p-|x|^p}{h}$ when $|x|=x$ and $|x|=-x$? I don't see how this may help actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Break it up into cases.   $x>0$ and $x<0$ are trivial as once $h$ is sufficiently close to 0,  so is $x+h$.

The $x=0$ case break into two one sided limits,  one as $h\to 0^-$, the other $h\to 0^+$.   This lets you get rid of the absolute value in your calculations.

Comment: I still get stuck when I factor $\frac{(x+h)^p-x^p}{h}$. Is there any technique that I have to know, or some trick? I need to factor $h$ out, right?

Comment: You can use the fact that that's the definition of the derivative of $x^p$

Comment: I'm not sure I expressed myself clearly, sorry if that's the case. My struggle is to factor $\frac{(x+h)^p-x^p}{h}$, so that I can get $px|x|^{p-2}$. In particular, I'm not sure how to get rid of the $h$ at the bottom, so the limit is not $\infty$ or undefined. So, my question is, what technique do I use to do this?

Comment: The exponential answer here shows how to calculate that limit as a derivative. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335500/proof-of-the-derivative-of-xn

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If $x>0$, you can evaluate the limit with $|h|<x$ so that $x+h>0$ and the limit is just the derivative of $x^p$ (because $|x|^p=x^p,|x+h|^p=(x+h)^p$). The function is even, so that its derivative is odd.

The only remaining case is for $x=0$,

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|h|^p}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}|h|^{p-1}=0$$ for $p>1$. Finally, if $x=0,p=1$ the derivative does not exist.