# Derivative of $x^n$ for $n < 0$

Tags: derivatives

I know that you can prove the derivative of $x^n$ where $n > 0$ using the bionomial theorem etc. Now I have looked online and couldn't find out but I'd like to ask here, is the a proof for the derivative of $x^n$ where $n<0$?

Comment: MathJax tip: curly braces `{}` are used for grouping, and are not rendered. If you want to put a superscript containing more than a single symbol, group those symbols in curly braces. For example, `$x^{-n}$` renders as $x^{-n}$.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1335531) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you both!

Comment: Note that you can directly prove for negative integer $n$ by noting that $(x+h)^n-x^n=[x^{-n}-(x+h)^{-n}]/x^n(x+h)^n$, and then applying the binomial theorem to the numerator.

Comment: Once I've applied the theorem to the numerator how do I clear up the denominator?

Comment: Nevermind I've done it